# Is there a way to tell unix expand command not to change line endings?

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin, expand

I'm using cygwin version of expand with bash shell.

When calling `expand` to replace all `\t` with   (spaces) `expand` also changes all newline endings from `\n` to `\r\n`.

I'm using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$1

TMPFILE=/tmp/temporaryExpander

EXTENSIONS=(
    cpp
    cxx
    h
    java
    txt
    cs
    csproj
    vcproj
    sln
    csdproj
)

function TabsToSpacesForFile
{
    relativeFilePath=$1
    absoluteFilePath=`pwd`/$relativeFilePath

    expand --tabs=4 $absoluteFilePath > $TMPFILE
    cat $TMPFILE > $absoluteFilePath
}

for project in `ls $BRANCH`
do
    for extension in "${EXTENSIONS[@]}"
    do
        find $BRANCH/$project -name "*\.${extension}" | while read file; do TabsToSpacesForFile "$file"; done
    done
done
```

Comment: I know this doesn't solve you problem directly but you could use this command to replace tabs with spaces: `cat file | tr "\t" " "`.

Comment: btw, to convert from relative path to absolute path, I would recommend using `readlink -f`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
expand --tabs=4 $absoluteFilePath > $TMPFILE
cat $TMPFILE > $absoluteFilePath
```

why not try:

```
sed -i 's/\t/    /g' $absoluteFilePath
```

that shouldn't mess with the line endings at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do `dos2unix "$file"` to convert the line endings back to unix style.

> The Dos2unix package includes utilities "dos2unix" and "unix2dos" to convert plain text files in DOS
>          or Mac format to Unix format and vice versa.
>
> In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a combination of two characters: a
>          Carriage Return (CR) followed by a Line Feed (LF). In Unix text files a line break is a single
>          character: the Line Feed (LF). In Mac text files, prior to Mac OS X, a line break was single
>          Carriage Return (CR) character. Nowadays Mac OS uses Unix style (LF) line breaks.

Comment: I'd rather revert the line endings to what they were before my conversion. Unfortunately it's not like all files have unix line endings right now.

Comment: So you have some files with `dos` line ending and some with `unix` and you want them all to keep there original?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function TabsToSpacesForFile
{
    relativeFilePath=$1
    absoluteFilePath=`pwd`/$relativeFilePath
    absoluteFilePathLineEndings=false
    expand --tabs=4 $absoluteFilePath > $TMPFILE
    file $absoluteFilePath | grep -q CRLF && dos2unix $TMPFILE
    cp $TMPFILE $absoluteFilePath
}
```

I am assuming all to be text files; no binary files.

Also, you should perhaps `rm $TMPFILE` at the end. Quote the variables for $absoluteFilePath etc if needed.